# Clojure static inner class instantiation issues (interop issues)

Tags: clojure

I am trying to use a static inner class from a Java library into Clojure.

The inner class is [InMemoryLookupCache.Builder](http://deeplearning4j.org/doc/org/deeplearning4j/models/word2vec/wordstore/inmemory/InMemoryLookupCache.Builder.html).

I am always getting a `ClassNotFoundException`. Like with:

```
(import 'org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.inmemory.InMemoryLookupCache$Builder)
```

I am trying to write that Java code in Clojure without any success:

```
new InMemoryLookupCache.Builder().lr(2e-5).vectorLength(100).build();
```

However I am not able to instantiate that inner class even if I think I am right using the `$` syntax to access it.

If you want to try, use the following projects:

```
[org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core "0.0.3.3"]
[org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp "0.0.3.3"]
```

Comment: What part is failing, the import itself or the usage of the class?

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj the `import` is failing with `ClassNotFoundException` (just tried it)

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj yes the import. Otherwise I tried a `ns` import: `(:import org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.inmemory InMemoryLookupCache$Builder)` and then to use it like `InMemoryLookupCache$Builder` but it fails too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this](https://github.com/SkymindIO/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j-scaleout/deeplearning4j-nlp/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/models/word2vec/wordstore/inmemory/InMemoryLookupCache.java) is the class you are using, I don't see a Builder inner class?

EDIT:
This is working for me.  Changed the version of the library to the same one the example is using.

in project.clj:

```
(defproject clojure-scratch "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core "0.0.3.2.7"]
                 [org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-nlp "0.0.3.2.7"]])
```

in core.clj:

```
(ns clojure-scratch.core
  (:import (org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.inmemory
             InMemoryLookupCache
             InMemoryLookupCache$Builder)))

(println (new InMemoryLookupCache$Builder))
```

Comment: that is right. However, I should be missing something... If I check the history of that file, it is like if there never was one, but in their examples, they are clearly using that builder: https://github.com/SkymindIO/dl4j-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/word2vec/Word2VecExample.java

Comment: I did some more analysis. It turned out that they made major refactoring changes in version `0.0.3.3`. The previous version `0.0.3.2.7` does have the proper code. What was confusing is that the Java API and the examples didn't get properly updated...